# iOS - Access purchased videos list from iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I wanted to ask how can access the List Movies, Pod-cast, Songs purchased from iTunes pro-grammatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get access to films purchased via iTunes, they're protected by DRM, but you can get access to purchased film clips.

Have a look at the MediaPlayer framework. There's MPMediaQuery for querying the iTunes database and MPMediaPickerController which looks like it should let you pick films but only seems to work with songs. It's a moot point seeing as you can't do anything interesting with films it could pick if it only worked.

If it's just a demo, why not stick some non DRMed movies in your Documents folder and open the from there?